# python a compare list of a list with a list

Tags: python, list, compare

I am working on a project that recognize letters from a photo and then compare them with a user input. Using the OCR i get 3 values of the letters in the photo `['Example', x and y coords, rotation]`
and the user input as a string which i transformed into a list.

Here is an example: 
user input:

Example. I will change it to `List1 = ['E','X','A','M',...]` and the letters from the photo:  `List2 = [['A',x,y,rotation],['E',x,y,rotation],['R',x,y,rotation],.....]`

How can i compare List2 first element of the first list in list2 which is 'A' with List1. Letter can be matched and there is letter just want to remove here is 'R' and at the end get a new List3[]= with the value from list2 match with the letters from list1

I want to compare the two lists by the letters and in the end add the matched one from list2 to a new list.... example, List1 = [A, W , O , R , K] <- Input List2 = [[“A”, 56, 75, 12], [D,42,35,-5], [K,20,41,5] ,[ O,61,31,16], [R,55,10.0], [W,14,10,30],[ L,82,15,-41],[ K.11.2.3] <- Letters in Work space List3 = [this list will get the matched ones in list2 with list1 by letters like ([“A”, 56, 75, 12]...)]

Comment: That last sentence is almost impossible to understand. Do you think you could make it a little clearer? It would help if you showed 1: what you're starting with. 2: the result you want. It seems like you just want `[l for l in List2 if l[0] in List1]`

Comment: I want to compare the two lists by the letters and in the end add the matched one from list2 to a new list....   example, List1 = [A, W , O , R , K] <- Input
List2 = [[“A”, 56, 75, 12], [D,42,35,-5], [K,20,41,5] ,[ O,61,31,16], [R,55,10.0], [W,14,10,30],[ L,82,15,-41],[ K.11.2.3] <- Letters in Work space
List3 = [this list will get the matched ones in list2 with list1 by letters like ([“A”, 56, 75, 12]...)]

Answer (score 0):

Convert Second list into the pd.DataFrame and then you can easily get your hands on first column if you set index = False  or else on the second column.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is what you are after:

```
for l in List2:
    for l1 in List:
        if l1 == l[0]:
            List3.append(l1)
```